# Copy-paste from question to snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

When I'm editing a stack snippet, I often want to copy code from the original question into the snippet. But while the snippet editor is on display, there's no way to access the question, other than opening another tab/window. What I often do instead is copy all the code in the question to the clipboard, open the snippet editor, then paste it all in and revise it to what I want. But when the original code is poorly designed, that ends up being more work than just copying the bits and pieces that I want.

There could be a "View Question" button that pops up the question over the snippet editor and allows copying. Or maybe the Snippet Editor could be draggable and resizable, so you can reveal the question and copy from it; but this would require that it not be purely modal.

Comment: So what you suggest? Feature request should contain some suggestion as to what to add/change exactly, otherwise it is a bug report or just a discussion.

Comment: I thought I could leave the specific UI up to the developer, but I've added some suggestions.